# Graphical representation of Job

Tags: websphere-liberty, jsr352

Is it possible to have graphical representation to submit and restart the jobs and is it possible to display job progress and job status information to the user.

Comment: Please ask a more detailed question and state what you have already tried.

Comment: Why should it be impossible? Did you find evidence for that?

Comment: @ Blubberguy22 Currently I am using Job JobOperatorServlet to start, restart the job. So if I type servlet url and providing the job parameter in that URL will start or restart the job.Is it possible to have Graphical representation to JobOperatorServlet. Once Job is submitted is it possible to to have job progress bar in the same page and other properties of job related information in the same page.It is like page which should have capabilities to mange the jobs in single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present there is no graphical front end for JSR-352 support in Liberty.  There is a REST interface that you can use instead of the JobOperator API that could be used underneath a graphical interface.  Documentation on that is here:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_batch_rest_api.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5 and see also the whitepaper here:  https://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP102632.
Furthermore, you can also subscribe to batch events published at significant points in the life of a job to monitor progress.  That is described here:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_batch_monitoring.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5 and see also the whitepaper here:  https://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP102603.
Finally, there is an open requirement (developerworks/rfe) asking for Admin Center support to help manage batch jobs.  You may want to vote for that requirement.  The requirement number is 87445.

Comment: Thank you @DFollis.I have voted for the 87445 rfe request.